# Android: empty Default HttpClient queue

Tags: android, httpclient

I have two activities that both make different http requests to my server when started.
When I switch back and forth between them the responses start to have some delay because they get queued up on top of eachother.

I would like to empty and abort this connections and just keep the latest one.

I tried

```
httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

but it throws

```
05-14 08:20:51.137  12627-12997/com.tesis.restapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Manager is shut down.
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.assertStillUp(SingleClientConnManager.java:175)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:213)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$1.getConnection(SingleClientConnManager.java:191)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:580)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:512)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:490)
        at support.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:96)
        at fragments.MainFragment$FetchOrders.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:150)
        at fragments.MainFragment$FetchOrders.doInBackground(MainFragment.java:129)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)...
```

Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Not getting you. You want to start two call parallely?

Comment: I want to just keep the queue restricted to one call. When creating a new request, I want the app to abort all previous and start with this one.

Comment: did you try this httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();

Comment: Tried it just now. Didn't do much. my request keep piling up. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just cancelling the AsyncTask that carried out the HttpRequest did the trick!